# Installing dashboard for openstack errors

Tags: apache2, openstack

I'm trying to install openstack dashboard, accordingly to the manual (vers. Juno)
But the install fails, running this cli:

```
apt-get install openstack-dashboard apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi memcached python-memcache
```

getting several errors like this one:

```
 Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-django/python-django_1.6.1-2ubuntu0.6_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
```

I can ping and telnet on port 80

```
ping 91.189.92.201
PING 91.189.92.201 (91.189.92.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.92.201: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=41.2 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.201: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=41.4 ms

--- 91.189.92.201 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 41.221/41.324/41.427/0.103 ms

telnet 91.189.92.201 80
Trying 91.189.92.201...
Connected to 91.189.92.201.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

---

I can ping and telnet on port 80

```
$ ping 91.189.92.201
PING 91.189.92.201 (91.189.92.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.92.201: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=41.2 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.201: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=41.4 ms

--- 91.189.92.201 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 41.221/41.324/41.427/0.103 ms

#  telnet 91.189.92.201 80
Trying 91.189.92.201...
Connected to 91.189.92.201.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The slightly older version of python-django in your output indicates that you may need to refresh your package lists.  To make sure your packaging system is always working with current information, it is advisable to do this before package installations:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
```